# How to study/analysis a MySQL DB tables relationships?

Tags: mysql, relationship, erd

I'm given a MySQL DB that contain 108 tables. Is there a way or tool (software) to be  able to see how these tables are connected (hopefully in a visual way) so I would be able to understand the usage of each table and how everything is working together.
I'm accessing them through something called "MySQL Tools" -> "MySQL Administrator" with "Read Only" privileges.

Tables are all using InnoDB engine.

*I'm using Mac

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an ERD generator for MySQL.  Do a google search on 'MySQL ERD' and plenty of free options pop up.  I have not used this, however, I have heard decent things about  [DBDesigner](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/)

Comment: DBDesigner looks very interesting, but no support for Mac!
Any other suggestions?

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't notice you said a MAC. The only time I ever develop on a Mac is through Windows on VMFusion.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Yeah...but I prefer to use software directly on Mac. Using V.M. is a headache specially if you have to keep going back and forth a lot between Mac & PC.
let me know if you recommend something else for Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this will only happen "automatically" if the database is using foreign keys. in my experience, most mysql-based applications do not so you might be out of luck there.

Comment: That is, unfortunately (InnoDB vs MyISAM), true. However, I've heard that sybase powerdesigner attempts to reverse-engineer the triggers to find "declarative" (trigger-driven) relations. I don't know how successful it is at it, though.

Comment: They are using the InnoDB engine which support the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

[DB Visualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/) 
[MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/)